# FRM-40350 Query Caused No Records to be retrieved

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am new in Oracle forms. I  have connected my forms to the database. Then created data block choosing data block wizard. I have choosen of my database table ORDERS. I have inserted values in this ORDERS table in sqlplus. After creating ORDERS data block I run my forms through browser, I click on execute query on menu but it's not fetching the data from my database table. It says,
FRM-40350 Query Caused No REcords to be retrieved . But in sqlplus I have checked that the row created successfully and column is fill in value and my application forms is connected to my database. Then why my execute query not working? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you `commit`ed in your SQL*Plus session?

Comment: no, I didn't commited.

Comment: Only after the commit, the data inserted in that session becomes visible in other sessions (e.g. Oracle Forms, but also othe SQL*Plus sessions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're connected to the same user in both SQLPlus and Forms (you probably are, otherwise Forms wouldn't see that table and you wouldn't be able to base data block on it), you probably didn't **COMMIT** after inserting row(s) in SQLPlus.

---

Code you posted should be fixed (invalid datatype, missing column name, don't insert strings into DATE datatype column):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE ORDERS(
  2      order_id     NUMBER(20),
  3      customer_id  NUMBER(20),
  4      order_date   DATE, -- NUMBER(20),  --> date, not number
  5      order_status VARCHAR2(20),
  6      order_mode   VARCHAR2 (200),
  7      SALES_REP_ID NUMBER (20) );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO orders (
  2      order_id,
  3      customer_id,
  4      order_date,
  5      order_status,
  6      order_mode,
  7      sales_rep_id
  8  ) VALUES (
  9      0001,
 10      01,
 11      date '2008-02-11',  -- not '11-FEB-2008', it is a STRING
 12      '5',
 13      'direct',
 14      158
 15  );

1 row created.
```

This is what you're missing:

```
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE ORDERS(
 ORDER_ID NUMBER (20),
 CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(20),
 ORDER_DATE NUMBER (20),
 ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(20),
  VARCHAR2 (200),
 SALES_REP_ID NUMBER (20)
);
INSERT INTO ORDERS( ORDER_ID , CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_STATUS , ORDER_MODE , SALES_REP_ID )
VALUES ( 0001, 01 , '11-FEB-2008' , '5' , 'direct' , 158 ); I only  did this query in sqlplus

Comment: Right; although wrong (see my edited answer), I got the idea. You didn't COMMIT.

Comment: If I create table in sqldeveloper in same db , in sqlplus the table not created. How can I connect sqlplus and sqldeveloper though both are connected in same db,same username and password.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` is a DDL statement that does not need to be commited - it's immediately visible in all other session. `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are DML statements that only become visible after the `COMMIT`.

Comment: Well, if you created the table in SQL Developer, it already exists - you can't create it (again) using SQL Plus.

Comment: Thanks you are great , It's working fine now.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you made it work.